# Default install position of my FF toolbar?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, toolbar

My toolbar gets installed on top of the Firefox 4 window, how can I set it's default position to be elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the below link , it states the Extension etiquette for firefox..

I think you can see the things related to positioning

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Extension_etiquette

and i think the sample code should be like

```
<toolbar id="solvent-scrapeToolbar" 
  hidden="true" 
  flex="0.2"
  fullscreentoolbar="true"
  insertafter="FindToolbar">
```

for example

`insertbefore="browser-bottombox"` should place at the bottom

I would suggest another method, download any previous extensions which has option to move the location and try to read their code/content..

You will get an idea